# Doc Hollywood and Cars

Tags: analysis, cars, doc-hollywood

These two stories are identical. The characters are the same.

- Doc Hudson is the old Dr. in Doc Hollywood
- Benjamin Stone is Lightning
- The wrecker is the mechanic
- The Porsche is Loo

Both in small towns with the hero lost on the way to LA - can't leave without paying the fine in services, etc. There is even some of the same dialogue, "He-haw Hell" in both movies.

Is all that coincidental or not?

Comment: I haven't found an article yet that states from anyone at Pixar that Cars is based on, inspired by, and/or a reworking of Doc Hollywood. However I see A LOT of websites that point out the similarities and sites that believe Pixar stole lots of plots from former movies. I also see sites and youtube videos that show differences also. IMO, at the very least, I think you could presume that Cars has allusions to Doc Holloywood.

Comment: I noticed the similarities immediately but I’ve never seen an official acknowledgement. +1 for the question